# How to play MP3 with no file extension in Flex 4 Spark Video Player

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mp3

I have a mp3 that is retrieved from the server via "somepage.php?id=100". When I load this into spark VideoPlayer it doesn't work. But when I copy that URL and put it into the browser URL I get a dialog that asks if I want to download "sound.mp3".

UPDATE!!!

// in the creation complete handler
var audioElement:AudioElement = new AudioElement();
audioElement.resource = new URLResource(path);
audioElement.resource.mediaType = MediaType.AUDIO;
videoPlayer.source = audioElement.resource;

// and in the video player you must set autoDisplayFirstFrame to FALSE

It seems the audio is cued up in order when added to the creation complete meaning that if one audio file is loading another will not start until after the first has completed.

Comment: Do you want advise on how to fix the PHP page on your server, or on how to open the file in Spark VideoPlayer?

Comment: How to open the file in Spark VideoPlayer.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the PHP script is returning the right media type:

```
header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
```

If it isn't, a player should indeed refuse to play it.

If it *is* OK, and Spark is just being stupid and guessing filetype from the file extension instead of the proper media type, you might try to work around it by hacking the URL, eg. `somepage.php/something.mp3?id=100` or maybe `somepage.php?id=100&ignore=/something.mp3`.

Comment: The server was not returning the mp3 content type. The hack worked! 

Here is what was being returned:

Content-Disposition attachment; filename=noooooo.mp3;
Content-Length 214922
Content-Transfer-Encoding binary
Content-Type application/octet-stream

Comment: The hack does not seem to be working. It looks like I need the content type set.

Comment: var audioElement:AudioElement = new AudioElement();
audioElement.resource = new URLResource("http://stage.domain.com/api/get_file_content.php?id=100");
audioElement.resource.mimeType = "audio/mpeg"; // this works and...
//audioElement.resource.mediaType = MediaType.AUDIO; // ...this works too
video1.source = audioElement.resource;